# Get certain elements in a variable with the same name as the id without writing getElementByID many times?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, getelementbyid

I have so many scripts that start like this (normally after a DOMContentLoaded event):

```
mythis      = document.getElementById("mythis");
mythat      = document.getElementById("mythat");
naming      = document.getElementById("naming");
isdev       = document.getElementById("isdev");
easier      = document.getElementById("easier");
remember    = document.getElementById("remember");
your        = document.getElementById("your");
stuff       = document.getElementById("stuff");
```

But it's so bloated code. So I wondered if there wasn't an easier way without using eval().

This could be considered as using the benefits from '[named access on the window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)' ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)) (standard in some browsers), but safer and only for your choice of variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
["mythis","mythat","naming","isdev","easier","remember","your","stuff"].forEach(s=>{
        window[s]=document.getElementById(s)
    })
```